# Finding the range of one column that is true in another column

Tags: sql, distinct-values

I am trying to write the correct sql query to find the range in one column that will only return what is true in another column.

EX. Which product Southwest region 10 - 20 are ISO certified?

Comment: Are these columns in the same database table?

Comment: Yes. Both columns are in the same table.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the structure of the table. Include the name of the table, then names of the columns and the data-types of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table contains Id, Product, Region, ISO columns

```
SELECT p.Product
FROM TableName
WHERE Region BETWEEN 10 AND 20 AND ISO=True
```

Comment: @Abra Yes. Sorry about that. I have corrected that one.